# Find index when given X and Y values

Tags: math

Image a graph with x and y coordinates.

[image]

I am given the X and Y values of the graph and i need a formula to determine the index of the tile.

Comment: Index = 5 * (y-1) + (x-1)

Answer (score 0):

We can try to use a programming based solution here, namely writing a double for loop which will iterate over the tiles.

```
for (int row=1; row <= 4; ++row) {
    for (int col=1; col <= 5; ++col) {
        int index = (row - 1) * 5 + (col - 1);
    }
}
```

Assuming that the `Y` values correspond to the rows, and the `X` values to the columns, this yields the following formula:

```
index = 5*(Y - 1) + (X - 1)
```

### Demo

The above demo is in C, though it should run in several other languages with little modification.

Comment: The formula is fine, but what is the purpose of the loop? This is just basic indexing.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Strictly speaking SO is for programming questions only.  I added code to make the question valid.

Comment: You can't make that question valid my friend. All you did is confuse an otherwise respectable answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist In your estimation, is it plausible to assume that the OP intends to program in some form to _generate_ that grid?  If not, then it would seem very strange to me to come to a programming site for help.

Comment: Also, that you downvoted an otherwise correct answer without also downvoting the question is bizarre.  We're not "friends."

Comment: I voted to close the question. I downvoted your answer for irrelevant nonsense and encouraging this sort of question. I wouldn't downvote a good answer just for the latter. Fortunately, the opinion of a lone nut will not affect your rep much.